# Twilio forwarding SMS to a different number and manage conversation

Tags: sms, twilio

I want a user to send an SMS to a Twilio number. For simplicity, let's call the user phone number that sends an SMS "A" and the Twilio number "B". I want to add a little magic to the message, and then I want to forward the message to another phone number, let's call this phone number "C", that is associated with Twilio number "B".

A -> (B -> server) -> C.

When phone number "C" receives the message, it shows that it comes from phone number "B". However, I need it to show that the message was sent from phone number "A".

If this can be set up, I will also need to know how to make sure that if "C" sends a message that is intended for "A" that it will be forced to go to through the server and then be delivered to "A" showing that the number it was sent from is "B".

I'm sure that there is an easy fix, but I just can't seem to figure out how to make this happen. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried for this so far?

Comment: Is there a way this can be done ? Any findings ? Doesn't look too trivial to me !!!! @philnash

Comment: All of this can be done except for the bit where person C receives the message and it looks like it comes from number A (and consequently sending a message back to A going through Twilio). We can't change the sender ID of an SMS to spoof someone else's number, so it must come from the Twilio number. Here's how to forward an SMS: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-forward-my-sms-messages-to-another-phone-number